# React hooks best practice storing refs to third party libraries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a wrapper hooks library around `pusher-js` to publish into the wild. For each hooks (i.e. `useChannel`, `usePresenceChannel`, `useTrigger`), I need to keep a reference to the Pusher instance, i.e. new Pusher() stored in a Context Provider. I am allowing third party auth to be passed in so I need to create the Pusher instance on the fly. I'm unsure whether I should be storing this in a useState or useRef.

The `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` rules complain with various combinations of useState and useRef to store this. I'm also seeing undesirable side effects when trying to clean up correctly with each. I'm unsure what's considered best practice.

Here's a simplified implementation with the important details. See comments 1. 2. and 3. below for my questions.

```javascript
// PusherContext.jsx
export const PusherContext = React.createContext();
export function PusherProvider({key, config, ...props}){
  // 1. Should I store third party libraries like this?
  const clientRef = useRef();
  // vs const [client, setClient] = useState();

  // when config changes, i.e. config.auth, re-create instance
  useEffect(() => {
    clientRef.current && clientRef.current.disconnect();
    clientRef.current = new Pusher(key, {...config});
  }, [clientRef, config]);

  return <PusherContext.Provider value={{ client }} {...props} />
}

// useChannel.js
export function useChannel(
  channelName, 
  eventName, 
  callback, 
  callbackDeps
){
  const { client } = useContext(PusherContext);
  const callbackRef = useCallback(callback, callbackDeps);  

  // 2. Or should I be using state instead?
  const [channel, setChannel] = useState();
  // vs. const channelRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(client.current){
      const pusherChannel = client.current.subscribe(channelName);
      pusherChannel.bind(eventName, callbackRef.current);
      setChannel(pusherChannel);
    }

    // can't cleanup here because callbackRef changes often.
    // 3. eslint: Mutable values like 'client.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component
  }, [client.current, callbackRef])

  // cleanup for unbinding the event
  // re-bind makes sense with an updated callback ref
  useEffect(() => {
    channel.unbind(eventName)
  }, [client, channel, callbackRef, eventName]);

  // cleanup for unsubscribing from the channel
  useEffect(() => {
    clientRef.unsubscribe(channelName);
  }, [client, channelName])
}
```

Any advice, past examples or patterns are greatly appreciated as I want to nail this one!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the ref to hold a new instance of `Pusher` as [recommended by Dan](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1105930134186532864?lang=en).

You don't need to clean up initially by doing null check and disconnect (`clientRef.current && clientRef.current.disconnect()`) in the inside effect because whenever the `useEffect` is run, React will disconnect when you handle it in the return statement.

```
export function PusherProvider({ key, config, ...props }) {
  // 1. Should I store third party libraries like this?
  const clientRef = useRef();
  // vs const [client, setClient] = useState();

  // when config changes, i.e. config.auth, re-create instance
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   clientRef.current && clientRef.current.disconnect();
  //   clientRef.current = new Pusher(key, { ...config });
  // }, [clientRef, config]);

  // Create an instance, and disconnect on the next render
  // whenever clientRef or config changes.
  useEffect(() => {
    clientRef.current = new Pusher(key, { ...config });

    // React will take care of disconnect on next effect run.
    return () => clientRef.current.disconnect();
  }, [clientRef, config]);

  return <PusherContext.Provider value={{ client }} {...props} />;
}
```

For the second case, I tried as much to write suggestions in-line below.

The gist is that, `un/subscription` are related events, thus should be handled in the same effect (as it was the case for `PusherProvider`).

```
// useChannel.js
export function useChannel(channelName, eventName, callback, callbackDeps) {
  const { client } = useContext(PusherContext);
  const callbackRef = useCallback(callback, callbackDeps);

  // 2. Or should I be using state instead?
  // I believe a state makes sense as un/subscription depends on the channel name.
  // And it's easier to trigger the effect using deps array below.
  const [channel, setChannel] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // do not run the effect if we don't have the Pusher available.
    if (!client.current) return;

    const pusherChannel = client.current.subscribe(channelName);
    pusherChannel.bind(eventName, callbackRef.current);
    setChannel(pusherChannel);

    // Co-locate the concern by letting React
    // to take care of un/subscription on each channel name changes
    return () => client.current.unsubscribe(channelName);

    // Added `channelName` in the list as the un/subscription occurs on channel name changes.
  }, [client.current, callbackRef, channelName]);

  // This.. I am not sure... 
  // cleanup for unbinding the event
  // re-bind makes sense with an updated callback ref
  useEffect(() => {
    channel.unbind(eventName);
  }, [client, channel, callbackRef, eventName]);

  // Moved it up to the first `useEffect` to co-locate the logic
  // // cleanup for unsubscribing from the channel
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   clientRef.unsubscribe(channelName);
  // }, [client, channelName]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sung - All looks good, however, pusher is unsubscribing whenever client.current changes (`return () => client.current.unsubscribe(channelName);`) - i.e. a member is added or removed. I'm thinking I have to have an isReady state in the context that I can use to bind.

Comment: Yeah. I do not know exactly how the Pusher is to be implemented so you are probably right so long as you don't fake the deps list.

Comment: Can't do that with `eslint`! Keeps you in check. I've opted to separate channels and events into their own hooks.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-pusher

Comment: Additionally, [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html?source=post_page-----eb7c15198780----------------------#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) are another solution to this issue.